# Azure DevOps: How to associate jUnit/TestNG results with Test Case executions?

Tags: azure, testing, junit, devops

I have been running Java/SHAFT Engine(selenium wrapper+reporter) on an Azure Pipeline to get results. Typically, the SHAFT Engine HTML report had been enough, however in a project there is combined manual and automation testing, and we need a common way to keep track of the results. If I were writing in xUnit for example, in C#, Azure DevOps provides a plugin already that maps test runs of test case items with results from the Pipeline's code as long as the test case ID is written in the annotations or is mapped through Visual Studio's mapping feature. However, this is not the case for jUnit/TestNG. Is there a workaround for this, or is the only solution a new plugin using Azure's REST API?

Let me quantify the problem better below, to express it more precisely:

**Problem:**
Map test results from pipelines to test runs.

**Given**

1. jUnit test results from Azure Pipeline run(typically called Test Results as seen below)
   [image]
2. The test case runs (results from test case execution)
3. TestNG listener in the code, which apparently is viewed as jUnit anyway from Azure